# Is there a way for uploading file by asking user input local file path in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to have a charfield in a form to ask user input a absolute file path then bound the file to Request.file object? I think this is quite routine but I cannot use forms.fileField to do this since I cannot find a argument you can input file path. I searched but seems no related posts can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this, because there is no way to give a path to a browser file upload field - for very good security reasons imposed by the browsers themselves.

Comment: I see, thanks so much! Tried forms.FileField(widget=TextInput), but not working.